# How to calculate in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, calc

I am trying to calculate with the uptime-seconds from my Raspberry Pi. I need to get the hours and minutes. I use

```
upSeconds = `/usr/bin/cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime`
```

to get the seconds now I have to calculate to get to the hours and minutes, how do I calculate with Ruby, from Objective C I know it should work with `/, *, +, -` but how do I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked with ObjC but probably the operators are exactly the same:

```
upSeconds = `/usr/bin/cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime`

seconds = upSeconds.chomp.to_i # remove "\n" at the end and pass to int (ms lost)
hours = seconds / (60*60)
minutes = (seconds - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60
```